# Converter for bound data in style

Tags: wpf, xaml

Can't see the trees through the forest.
Trying a simple databinding and I want to format the value with a converter. (In this converter example, numeric data that is 0 is not displayed.)

Resource:

```
    <conv:FormattingConverter x:Key="FormattingConverter"/>
    <Style x:Key="EGTSTextBoxInt" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CC_BACKGROUND}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource CC_FOREGROUND}" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource DefaultFont}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource DefaultFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
        <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Normal" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
    </Style>
```

Textbox:

```
    <TextBox Name="Bill_Item"
             Grid.Column="6"
             MinWidth="46"
             MinHeight="23"
             Style="{StaticResource EGTSTextBoxInt}"
             Text="{Binding Path=Item, Mode=TwoWay,
                    Converter={StaticResource FormattingConverter},
                    ConverterParameter=\{0:G\}}" />
```

What I want to do is get the Converter code embedded in the style so that I don't have to spell it out in each Text=line.

Adding code behind the XAML to do anything for this is not an option!
I am looking for a pure XAML method.

I am still trying to grasp how certain things are done in Styles.

Brian

Comment: You can't have part of a setter in your style.  I.E. you either need your whole text binding line in the style or none of it; you can't do half.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.
But before you even start:

- It's heavy
- It's utterly useless in your case

**1) Define a custom markup extension**
The idea is to inherit from the Binding markup extension that allows you to write `Text ="{Binding SomeProperty}"`.
You can find an example of someone who made his own binding [here](http://www.paulstovell.com/wpf-delaybinding)
This solution does not allow you to put the feature in a style.

**2) Define an attached property**
that will modify the Binding of the default property of a control (in your case, Text is the default property of TextBox, as you can do `<TextBox>my text</TextBox>`) in order to use the converter you want, automatically.
This actually allows you to put set this attached property in a style. It is, however, very bad practice. It's as bad a magic strings.

**3)Don't do this, just don't.**
Write the converter each time.

Comment: Is there a way to do the converter with the parameter via a resource (ie global change to the formats being used)

Comment: Yes, make it two attached properties: one to mark the control as autoconverted, one to set the parameter. Then if it's meant to be global, put it as implicit style in app.xaml

Comment: Moved the setting of the format to a label and have the converter look up the value of the label from a list loaded at startup (or if it gets a proper format command, uses it).  This allows us to build XAML on the fly, have the format changeable from one single location and can even support changes down to a user level if we want.

Answer (score 0):

The `Text` property of the TextBox is about data.  The `Style` property is about what that data looks like.  It doesn't make sense to attach a Converter to a Style.

Edit: I think I see what you're trying to say now.  You want `Text="{Binding Path=Item}"` in one place and `<Setter Property="Text" Value="~somehow get the converter in here and have it applied to the existing text property which is bound to Items~" />`

As mydogisbox mentioned, I don't think you can split up these ideas in two places like that.

Comment: This is about how the data looks.  Blanking a field that is 0 is about the same as changing background when a value is 0 or negative.

Comment: Is that was you're actually trying to do?

Comment: That and format the data (ie date in mm/dd/yyyy format or date/time in mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm A/P and currency to 2 decimals or float to a set number of places.

Answer (score 0):

`Converters` are for converting one value into another value, so they cannot be used without the value they are converting

You can however use `StringFormat` in your binding to format values without a Converter

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Item, StringFormat=G}" />
```

You could also create a class that inherits from `Binding` class and sets the default `StringFormat`, although I feel this is more trouble than it's worth

```
<TextBox Text="{local:NumberBinding Path=Item}" />
```

And if you are ever working with Labels instead of TextBoxes, you can apply a style setter to `ContentStringFormat`, which will apply formatting to the Label's `Content`

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="ContentStringFormat" Value="G" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Problem with stringformat is that it has no control for blanking on 0 or out of date range.  Would prefer to use that instead of a converter, but never found a way to do it with the options we need.

Comment: @BRisley You can use a `DataTrigger` to display a blank value if the value equals 0 or `DateTime.MinValue`